# Atomic update in threaded lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, thread-safety

I think updating an atomic value this way inside a thread is not good (the sum doesn't look good sometimes)

```
    std::atomic<double> e(0);

    auto worker = [&] (size_t begin, size_t end, std::atomic<double> & acc) {
      double ee = 0;
      for(auto k = begin; k != end; ++k) {
        ee += something[k];
      }
      acc.store( acc.load() + ee );
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(nbThreads);
    const size_t grainsize = miniBatchSize / nbThreads;

    size_t work_iter = 0;
    for(auto it = std::begin(threads); it != std::end(threads) - 1; ++it) {
      *it = std::thread(worker, work_iter, work_iter + grainsize, std::ref(e));
      work_iter += grainsize;
    }
    threads.back() = std::thread(worker, work_iter, miniBatchSize, std::ref(e));

    for(auto&& i : threads) {
      i.join();
    }
```

while using a lock guard seems to be ok

```
    std::atomic<double> e(0);
    std::mutex m;

    auto worker = [&] (size_t begin, size_t end, std::atomic<double> & acc) {
      double ee = 0;
      for(auto k = begin; k != end; ++k) {
        ee += something[k];
      }
      {
          const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
          acc.store( acc.load() + ee );
      }
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(nbThreads);
    const size_t grainsize = miniBatchSize / nbThreads;

    size_t work_iter = 0;
    for(auto it = std::begin(threads); it != std::end(threads) - 1; ++it) {
      *it = std::thread(worker, work_iter, work_iter + grainsize, std::ref(e));
      work_iter += grainsize;
    }
    threads.back() = std::thread(worker, work_iter, miniBatchSize, std::ref(e));

    for(auto&& i : threads) {
      i.join();
    }
```

Am I right, what am I missing here ? is the std::ref(e) the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want both the load and store to happen as an atomic action. Currently your code does:

```
acc.store(acc.load() + ee);
```

Now imagine that a thread is interrupted right after `load()` is executed (let's call the loaded value `acc_old`). Another thread does its thing (and thus modifies `acc`) and then the first thread runs again. It won't reload `acc`, since it's already loaded its value. So this thread will now update `acc` to contain `acc_old + ee`. And bam, wrong result.

Instead use either [`fetch_add`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) or [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith2). Both guarantee atomic behavior for the whole addition operation. I.e.:

```
acc += ee; // or
acc.fetch_add(ee);
```

**Edit:** Note that these functions are only supported for floating point atomics starting in C++20. For integral types they are supported from C++11 onward. So if you need floating point, you'll likely have to stick to using a mutex. In that case I'd suggest wrapping the double value and the mutex in a single class, so you can't accidentally use it the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line:

`acc.store( acc.load() + ee );`

there are 2 operations load and store, in the interval between them, another thread can change the value.

Unfortunately atomic  does not support fetch_add.

You can try this:

```
    auto atomic_fetch_add = [](std::atomic<double>* obj, double arg)
    {
        auto expected = obj->load();
        while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(obj, &expected, expected + arg))
            ;
        return expected;
    };

    std::atomic<double> e(0);

    auto worker = [&] (size_t begin, size_t end, std::atomic<double> & acc) {
      double ee = 0;
      for(auto k = begin; k != end; ++k) {
        ee += something[k];
      }
      // acc.store( acc.load() + ee );
      atomic_fetch_add(&acc, ee);
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(nbThreads);
    const size_t grainsize = miniBatchSize / nbThreads;

    size_t work_iter = 0;
    for(auto it = std::begin(threads); it != std::end(threads) - 1; ++it) {
      *it = std::thread(worker, work_iter, work_iter + grainsize, std::ref(e));
      work_iter += grainsize;
    }
    threads.back() = std::thread(worker, work_iter, miniBatchSize, std::ref(e));

    for(auto&& i : threads) {
      i.join();
    }
```

Although there's no guarantee that atomic doesn't use mutexes, so you'd have to check your implementation.